# Performing raster to polygon conversion in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster-conversion

I have done raster to polygon conversion in ArcMap 10.3. The polygon shape is not the same as the raster pixels.

How can I polygonize the raster so that the polygons follow the raster's cell boundaries?

[image]

Comment: Uncheck simplify when running Raster to Polygon tool, see the [help section](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/conversion-toolbox/raster-to-polygon.htm)

Comment: @BERA You gave a great answer in your comment. Have you thought about posting it as an official answer so that other readers can see this question has been answered?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need to uncheck "Simplify" when running Raster to Polygon tool, see the [help section](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/conversion-toolbox/raster-to-polygon.htm) of the tool.

[image]